# Supremum of $|e^z|$ when $|z|=R$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it correct to say that if $|z|=R$ then $|e^z|\le e^R$? My reasoning is that $|e^z|=|e^{Re^{i\theta}}|=e^{R\cos(\theta)}$ and since $\cos (\theta)\le 1$ and since $e^x$ is monotone, we should have $|e^z|\le e^R$. Is this right?

Comment: You have it correct.

Comment: Yes it's right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=R \exp(i\theta)=R (\cos\theta+i \sin \theta)$, then $\exp(z)=\exp(R \cos \theta) \exp(iR \sin \theta)$, thus $|\exp(z)|=\exp(R \cos \theta) \leq \exp(R)$.

Comment: So then, my reasoning is correct?

Comment: You need just one more word, as "monotone" could be either direction.  Say $\exp(x)$ is monotonically _increasing_ with $x$, and you have it.